# Comparing Two Arrays & Get the Percent that Match - Java

Tags: java, arrays, compare

Background: Very new at Java, have little understanding. Would prefer a "point in the right direction" with explanation, if possible, than a copy/paste answer without explanation. If I want to stop being a novice, I need to learn! :)

Anyway, my goal is, as simply as possible, to be given 2 arrays numberList and winningNumbers, compare them, and return the percentage that numberList matches winningNumbers. Both array lengths will always be 10.

I have no idea where to start. I have been googling and going at this for 2 hours. My idea is to write a for loop that compares each individually integer in a string to one in the other, but I am not sure how to do that, or if there is a simpler method. I have little knowledge of arrays, and the more I google the more confused I become.

So far the only thing I have is

```
public double getPercentThatMatch(int[] winningNumbers) {}
```

numberList is preset.

Comment: Go through one array, and for each element check if it is in the other. If yes, add 10%.

Comment: Does order matter? If not, are they sorted? (Think about how this affects your future solution) I'd suggest that you simply play around with arrays. Loop, print. Try out the syntax.

Comment: Have you written any code with nested loops?

Comment: two questions, does the position of the numbers matter? and can a list have a number twice?

Comment: @Calum no it does not matter, and no it cannot.

Comment: @PM77-1 Once or twice, I have a decent understanding.

Comment: Then what ***exactly*** seems to be a problem?

Comment: @PM77-1 I think OP is attempting to get a conceptual understanding of the process in this. I would assume that she doesn't understand the use of nested for loops and how they can function to help her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way you could approach it is to:

1) convert both lists to sets.

2) subtract one from the other. ie if 4 are the same, the resulting set will have the 6 values not the same

3) 10 - (size of resulting set) * 100 = %

Comment: Sounds good, but what if two of the same numbers are in different places?

Comment: @NicoleI. That's the nice part about sets is that they have a method that allow you to see if the set contains a number. Regardless of where it's location is. But I personally think that if you are new to java, other data types are not something you should be using.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted to be pointed in the right direction, rather than havving proper code, and assuming you want to use arrays to solve the problem, try to put something like this in your method:

```html
(loop through arrayA){
  (loop through arrayB){
    if (current arrayA number is equal to current arrayB number){
        then increase match counter by one, since this exists.
        also break out of current arrayB loop. (Check next arrayA now.)
    }
  }
}
When done: return 100*matchCount/totalCount, as a double
```

So for every index in one array, you check against every other index of the other array. Increase a counter each time there's a match, and you'll be able to get a ratio of matches. If you use an integer as a counter, remember that division with integers acts funky, so you'd need to throw to a double:

```html
double aDoubleNumber = (double) intNumber / anotherIntNumber
```

Comment: What about if the numbers aren't exactly the same index? You would need nested for loops and check each arrayB[index2] with arrayA[index1].

Comment: Yeah, I first thought the task was that the numbers were at the same index. Added nested loops now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a runnable example of how you would compare the two arrays of `int`s to get a percent match.

```
public class LotteryTicket {
    int[] numberList;

    LotteryTicket(int... numbers) {
        numberList = numbers;
    }

    public int getPercentThatMatch(int[] winningNumbers) {
        Arrays.sort(numberList);
        Arrays.sort(winningNumbers);
        int i = 0, n = 0, match = 0;
        while (i < numberList.length && n < winningNumbers.length) {
            if (numberList[i] < winningNumbers[n]) {
                i++;
            } else if (numberList[i] > winningNumbers[n]) {
                n++;
            } else {
                match++;
                i++;
                n++;
            }
        }
        return match * 100 / winningNumbers.length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] winningNumbers = { 12, 10, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 1 };
        LotteryTicket ticket = new LotteryTicket(5, 2, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 1, 9, 0);
        int percentMatching = ticket.getPercentThatMatch(winningNumbers);
        System.out.println(percentMatching + "%");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
80%
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be easier if we consider them set. Let you have two set -

```
Set<Integer> s1 = //a HashSet of Integer;
Set<Integer> s2 = //a HashSet of Integer;
```

Now make a copy of `s1` for example `s11` and do the following thing  -

```
s1.retainAll(s2);
```

Now s1 contains only element of both sets - that is the intersection.

After that you can easily calculate the percentage

**Edit:**  You can convert the array to a set easily by using the following code snippet (I am assuming you have array of int) -

```
Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(somePrimiteiveIntArray));
```

I think this trick will works for other primitive type also.

Hope this will help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This will not work when there are duplicate numbers. (Just saying...)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to attempt to beat a dead horse and explain the easiest (conceptual) way to approach this problem I will include some code but leave a lot up to interpretation.

You have two arrays so I would change the overall method to something like this:

```
public double getPercentage(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {
  double percentage=0;
  for(/*go through the first array*/) {
    for(/*go through second array*/) {
      if(arrayA[i]==arrayB[j]) { /*note the different indices*/
        percentage++; /*count how many times you have matching values*/
        /* NOTE: This only works if you don't have repeating values in arrayA*/
      }
    }
  }
  return (percentage/arrayA.length)*100; /*return the amount of times over the length times 100*/
}
```

You are going to move through the first array with the first loop and the second array with the second loop. So you go through every value in arrayB for each value in arrayA to check.

Answer (score 0):

In my approach I tried storing the winning numbers in a Hashset (one pass iteration, O(n) )

And when iterating on the numberList, I would check for presence of number in Hashset and if so, I will increment the counter. (one pass iteration, so O(n) )

The percentage is thus calculated by dividing the counter with size of array.

See if the sample code makes sense:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Arraycomparison {

    public static void main(String ... args){

        int[] arr0 = {1,4,2,7,6,3,5,0,3,9,3,5,7};
        int[] arr1 = {5,2,4,1,3,7,8,3,2,6,4,4,1};
        HashSet set = new HashSet();

        for(int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++){
            set.add(arr1[j]);
        }

        double counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr0.length; i++){
            if(set.contains(arr0[i])){
                counter++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Match percentage between arrays : " + counter/arr0.length*100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use List over array, because that's a convenient way, but with array:

```
public class Winner {
public static void main(String... args) {
    double result = getPercentThatMatch(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}, new int[]{2,3,4,5,6});
    System.out.println("Result="+result+"%");
}

public static double getPercentThatMatch(int[] winningNumbers,
        int[] numberList) { // it is confusing to call an array as List
    int match = 0;
    for (int win : winningNumbers) {
        for (int my : numberList ){
            if (win == my){
                System.out.println(win + " == " + my);
                match++;
            }
        }
    }
    int max = winningNumbers.length; // assume that same length
    System.out.println("max:"+max);
    System.out.println("match:"+match);
    double devide = match / max; // it won't be good, because the result will be intm so Java will trunc it!
    System.out.println("int value:"+devide);
    devide = (double) match / max; // you need to cast to float or double
    System.out.println("float value:"+devide);

    double percent = devide * 100; 
    return percent;
}
```

}

Hope this helps. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
//For unique elements
getpercentage(arr1, arr2){
      res = arr1.filter(element=>arr2.includes(element))
   return res.lenght/arr2.lenght * 100;
 }

//For duplicate elements
getpercentage(arr1, arr2){
   const setA = Set(arr1);
   const setB = Set(arr2);
   Let res = [ ];
   for(let i of setB){
         if(setA.has(i)){
               res.push(i);
         }
  }
  return res.lenght/setA.size* 100;
```